# can you make the time between measurements as a variable?

Tags: regression

In longitudinal models (ex: regression), for the same person, I have never seen the time between two measurements being used as a variable. For example, if person1 has the first measurement on day 1 and the next measurement on day 5 .... but person2 has the first measurement on day1 and the next measurement on day 43 ..... I think it is logical that the second measurement will be closer to the first measurement for the first person compared to the second person. I also think that the variance should logically be smaller for the first person compared to the second person .... since a lot more can vary and change in longer periods of time compared to shorter periods of time.

Therefore, how come we the time passed between measurements is never used as a variable itself within longitudinal models? Is this because it is breaking statistical assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use differences in time as a variable. It is a good thing to consider time since most data sets are at least implicitly measured over time and may or may not have effects dependent on time.

However, you will need to consider what statistical model you are using. Pairs of differences in time may not be independent, in which case you should model that dependence.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, I would think the measurement times are decided by the designer, hence it does not make much sense to analyze them. Rather, we want to analyze data CONDITIONAL on those times. It is pretty much the same idea than in regression, where the regressors are fixed (not always) and the response variable is analyzed given the values of the regressors.

Comment: I would say that experimental designs are far from 'most cases' in many fields, where observational data is the norm. There, there is no 'designer' setting the measurement times.

Comment: @Kuku, there is probably a different meaning that you and I attach to "experimental design". Under that name I understand something that has been..., well, designed, meaning that the experimenter has the  choice of what to measure and when.  If that is the case, I think it makes little sense to analyze observation times as data, as they are arbitrarily chosen.  If data is observational, i.e. you do not have the choice of measurement times, then you are quite right. But I would not say in that case that data come from an "experimental design".

Comment: Indeed, I think we have the same meaning in mind. My point being in that in many fields, you will _in most cases **not**_ have 'an experimenter' who 'has the choice of what to measure and when', e.g. economical data.